# Mvc modal popup form doesn't work in dynamic tab after ajax request (doesn't load it's drop down data )

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Mvc modal popup form doesn't work when it's parent page is opened as a new tab ,But its works correctly when the page is opened as new window

popup form doesn't work in dynamic tab after ajax request when I try to use it's parent page in daynamic tab

some Html code in #parent page:

```
 <div class="container" style="width:40%;margin-top:2%">
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" 
 data-target="#myModal">clickme!</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a href="#" dir="ltr" class="close"
            data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
               <h3 class="modal-title" dir="rtl">clickme!/h3></div> 
             <div class="modal-body">
         <form id="myForm" dir="rtl">...
               <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" 
                data-dismiss="modal">cancel</a>
                        <input type="reset" value="show" class="btn 
                btn-success"  id="btnSubmit" />
                    </div>...
```

JQUERY code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            $("#loaderDiv").show();
            var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                //url:"/Home/Index",
                url: '@Url.Action("Get_Contracts_Steps", "Home")',
                data: myformdata,
                success: function () {
                    $("#loaderDiv").hide();
                    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle with code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @CarlosSá I didn't use it before and i don't know how to use it.

Comment: You go [here](https://jsfiddle.net/) and put as little of your code as possible to reproduce the issue. This is essential so other people can have a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve.
I'm going to make an educated guess and say that if you want your modal to show you probably need to change this `$("#myModal").modal("hide");` to this `$("#myModal").modal("show");`

Comment: @CarlosSá Tnx,Now the modal popup form works ,But immediately parent's page gets blank and stop working

Comment: I can't debug what I can't see, please share a working example of your issue so I can figure out what's happening